# How to chain together a sequence of POST requests in a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, fetch

I'm trying to create a Chrome extension that will make a series of POST requests, with the parameters of each one being dependent on the response of the previous one. I'm doing this using fetch. I understand how to use .then to handle dependencies between the components of a single query, but how would I handle the dependencies across queries? So currently my extension has code like

```
    fetch('http://localhost:8081/seed/create', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: new Headers({
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        }),
        body: '{"name": "nutch","seedUrls":[{"seedList": null,"url": "http://nutch1.apache.org/"}]}'
    })
            .then(function (response) {
                        return response.text();
            })
            .then(function (text) {
                seed = text;
                console.log(seed);
                document.getElementById("post").innerHTML = "responsePost: " + seed;

            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('FAIL: ', error);
            });

});
```

but I then need a second POST request that must wait for success from the first, and populate its payload with the previous response. Any tips?? 
thanks!

Comment: Put another .then on the end. Or use [async await](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/async-functions)

Comment: Ah thank you, I shall try that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'm going to answer my own question - I took Daniel's advice and used asyncs, which are a lot easier to read than promises (at least to me!):

```
async function getNutch(url) {

var response;
try {
    response = await fetch(url + "seed/create", {
        method: 'post',
        headers: new Headers({
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        }),
        body: getPayload(payloadEnums.SEED)
    });
    seedDir = await response.text();
    console.log(seedDir);
} catch (err) {
    console.log('fetch failed: ', err);
}
try {
    response = await fetch(url + "job/create", {
        method: 'post',
        headers: new Headers({
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        }),
        body: getPayload(payloadEnums.JOB)
    });
    console.log(await response.text());
} catch (err) {
    console.log('fetch failed: ', err);
}
```

}

which forces the two queries to run in sequence, with the second having to wait until the first completes - this is what I wanted. If there isn't this dependency, you should run the queries in parallel, as explained in the link Daniel provided on asy